# how to end a column of images in css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code
HTML

```
<div id="images" class="img"/>
 <img src="spiderman.png" alt=""/>
 <img src="superman.png" alt="" height="25%" width="25%"/>
 <img src="batman.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

css

```
.img {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 15%; 
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;

.img2 {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
  position: absolute;  
  right: 15%; 
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

JavaScript

```
(function() {

   function keyDown(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 65) {
       if (document.getElementsByClassName("img").length > 0) {
         document.getElementsByClassName("img")[0].className = "img2"
       } else {
         document.getElementsByClassName("img2")[0].className = "img"
       }
     }
   }

   document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
 })();
```

which outputs
[image]

This code aligns three images in a column and when i press the key 'a' it highlights those, the only problem i am having is the column doesn't seem to end and i do not know how to solve this.

Comment: Javascript you mentioned is not a javascript, its html.

Comment: your javascript is html

Comment: my mistake, updated now

Comment: why are the height and width of the superman image set to 25%?

Comment: to minimise the image

Answer (score 2):

the images div:

```
<div id="images" class="img"/>
```

is ending when it shouldn't. remove the slash and give it a run

```
<div id="images" class="img">
    <img src="spiderman.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="superman.png" alt="" height="25%" width="25%"/>
    <img src="batman.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

The issue seems to be with the superman.png image. It is using the original height and width of the image. So it shrinks the image for the display but still thinks it is large when measuring, hence the larger open space in the column.

Comment: still comes out with the same result

Comment: back to the drawing board then

Comment: can you humor me and remove the superman.png img and run it again

Comment: removed the superman png and the problem is still there, i think it might be to do with the styles i have used to format the images

Comment: try some random images you have instead of the superhero ones and see if it works.